# Search for multiple words via one django forms field

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

Hej!

I have a result table in which I can filter entries via a django form.
For example:
country: 'Sweden'

Where I would get all entries where 'Sweden' is the value in the column 'country'.

I want that if I type in 'Sweden, Germany' I'd get all the results where the country in my database is 'Sweden' or 'Germany'.
A boolean input ('Sweden OR/AND Germany') would also be great!

This is my current view:

```
#views.py
def search_institution(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SearchInstitutionsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            query_set = Institution.objects.filter(
                name__contains=form.cleaned_data['name']
               )
            context = {
                "result_data": list(query_set.values()),
                'form': form
            }
            return render(request, "search_form.html", context)
    else:
        form = SearchInstitutionsForm()

    context = {
        "result_data": list(Institution.objects.values()),
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "search_form.html", context)
```

I tried:

```
query_set = Institution.objects.filter(name__contains=x) for x in ['name']))

#and

query_set = Institution.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(name__contains=x) for x in ['name']))
```

and only got an empty result table.

```
query_set = Institution.objects.filter(
                name__search=form.cleaned_data['name']
               )
```

Here I got the error: >Unsupported lookup 'search' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.

Than I put django.contrib.postgres.search in my settings in installed apps and now geht the error >unrecognized token: "@"

My form and template:

```
#forms.py
class SearchInstitutionsForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', required=False)
```

```
#search_form.html
<form method="post">
  {{ form.as_table }}
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

Any ideas how to solve my problem?
Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @AmandeepSingh I tried ` query_set = Institution.objects.filter(reduce(operator.and_, (Q(name__contains=x) for x in ['name'])) ` but only get an empty result table.

Comment: Sorry i mentioned the wrong answer. It is applying `AND` operation but you are looking for `OR` operation

Answer (score 1):

Here, you can use Q function.
first, Split two keyword.

```
split = form.cleaned_data['name'].split(' ')
lookup = Q(name__contains=split[0]) | Q(name__contains=split[1])
query_set = Institution.objects.filter(
                    lookup
                   )
```

change your queryset with above code.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I can search for 2 words. Any idea how i can search for n-words?

And do I need multiple splits and lookups if I have multiple fields? 
For example name and country. I want to be able to search in multiple fields (this already works) with multiple words in the fields (this does not).

Comment: I dont know other way to solve this. I found this from my own logic. in this way, you can search n-words. And yes, for multiple fields you can use this code.

Comment: if I do it like the following I have to search for two words, otherwise my listIndex is out of range but will only get an empty table. More words give the same error.

``` split1 = form.cleaned_data['name'].split(',')
            lookup1 = Q(name__contains=split1[0]) | Q(name__contains=split1[1])
            split2 = form.cleaned_data['name'].split(' ')
            lookup2 = Q(abbreviation__contains=split2[0]) | Q(abbreviation__contains=split2[1])
            query_set = Institution.objects.filter(
                lookup1,
                lookup2, ```

Comment: count how many item are there after split , if it is 1 then get 0 index. if 2 get 0 and 1 index. add a condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest i could write and it should solve your question. I still have a gist that this can be done in a better way.

We want to get all those rows that contains any one of the names separated by comma. So we would like to have `OR` condition.

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_lookup_query(names_str):
    # Assuring names_str is not empty string i.e ""
    # Also it cannot contain white space only i.e "   "
    assert len(names_str.strip()) > 0, "names_str can neither be empty string nor contain white spaces only"

    # Splitting names based on comma and stripping white spaces 
    # from front and back for each name.
    names_list = [n.strip() for n in names_str.split(',')]

    # It would be good to have case insensitive match
    lookup_query = Q(name__icontains = names_list[0])
    len_names_list = len(names_list)
    if len_names_list > 1:
        for i in range(1,len_names_list):
            lookup_query |= Q(name__icontains = names_list[i])

    return lookup_query
```

Now you can get the queryset using this

```
names_str = form.cleaned_data['name']
lookup_query = get_lookup_query(names_str)
query_set = Institution.objects.filter(lookup_query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help and ideas!

I fixed my problem writing a new function to split the string in my forms.py inside my SearchInstitutionForm().

```
 def clean_name(self):
        name_str = self.cleaned_data["name"]
        if not name_str:
            return []
        name_list = [string.strip() for string in name_str.split(",")]
        return name_list
```

and added a separate query function to keep the code cleaner and simpler in my views.py. My views and queries got rather complicated :D

I now can add similar functions for all necessary parts.